# Sending multiple records in single mail: Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

Following is my **Trigger code**  which sends mail on **INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE** with info about the **old** and **new** record.

CODE :

```
create or replace TRIGGER EVAL_CHANGE_TRIGGER
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
  ON dw.sap_exclude_sites
  REFERENCING 
    NEW AS new
    OLD as old
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  log_action  EVALUATIONS_LOG.action%TYPE;
  I_MAIL_SUBJECT VARCHAR2(4000);
    I_MAIL_BODY VARCHAR2(4000);
    I_SIGNATURE VARCHAR2(4000);
    I_EMAIL_TO VARCHAR2(4000);
    I_EMAIL_FROM VARCHAR2(4000);
    I_EMAIL_HOST VARCHAR2(4000);
    I_ENV_NAME VARCHAR2(4000);
  OLD_val VARCHAR2(255);
  NEW_val VARCHAR(255);

BEGIN
  IF INSERTING THEN
    INSERT INTO EVALUATIONS_LOG 
    (log_date,action,old,new)
    values
    (SYSDATE,'INSERT',:old.WHSCODE,:new.WHSCODE);
        SELECT 'SAP_EXCLUDE_SITES-'||'INSERT:'||'-->Performed','This is old record::'||OLD||Chr(10)||'this is new record::'||NEW,SIGNATURE 
    into I_MAIL_SUBJECT,I_MAIL_BODY,I_SIGNATURE FROM dw.EVALUATIONS_LOG
     where LOG_DATE = (select max(LOG_DATE) from dw.EVALUATIONS_LOG);
    DLR_SEND_MAIL('kkishore@****.com',
    I_MAIL_SUBJECT,I_MAIL_BODY,'bidev-noreply@****.com','****.com'); 

  ELSIF UPDATING THEN
   INSERT INTO EVALUATIONS_LOG 
    (log_date,action,old,new)
    values
    (SYSDATE,'UPDATE',:old.WHSCODE,:new.WHSCODE);
    SELECT 'SAP_EXCLUDE_SITES-'||'UPDATE:'||'-->Performed','This is old record::'||OLD||Chr(10)||'this is new record::'||NEW,SIGNATURE 
    into I_MAIL_SUBJECT,I_MAIL_BODY,I_SIGNATURE FROM dw.EVALUATIONS_LOG
     where LOG_DATE = (select max(LOG_DATE) from dw.EVALUATIONS_LOG);
    DLR_SEND_MAIL('kkishore@****.com',
    I_MAIL_SUBJECT,I_MAIL_BODY,'bidev-noreply@****.com','****.com'); 
  ELSIF DELETING THEN
    INSERT INTO EVALUATIONS_LOG 
    (log_date,action,old,new)
    values
    (SYSDATE,'DELETE',:old.WHSCODE,:new.WHSCODE);
        SELECT 'SAP_EXCLUDE_SITES-'||'DELETE:'||'-->Performed','This is old record::'||OLD||Chr(10)||'this is new record::'||NEW,SIGNATURE 
    into I_MAIL_SUBJECT,I_MAIL_BODY,I_SIGNATURE FROM dw.EVALUATIONS_LOG
     where LOG_DATE = (select max(LOG_DATE) from dw.EVALUATIONS_LOG);
    DLR_SEND_MAIL('kkishore@****.com',
    I_MAIL_SUBJECT,I_MAIL_BODY,'bidev-noreply@****.com','****.com'); 
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('This code is not reachable.');



  END IF;

END;
```

My problem: Every time a Insert/update/delete happens, a mail is sent but what i need is to send multiple records/changes in single mail
instead of sending single mail for single DML.

For example: **sending mail after 15 min of last DML and send the new one's only.**

```
create OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EVAL_LOG AS 
BEGIN 

FOR I IN ( select LOG.LOG_DATE,LOG.ACTION,LOG.OLD,LOG.NEW from
dw.EVALUATIONS_LOG LOG
where to_char(log_date,'DD-MON-YYYY')
in (select max(to_char(log_date,'DD-MON-YYYY')) from dw.EVALUATIONS_LOG))
LOOP 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'Date : ' || i.log_date
  
 || '  ACTION : ' || i.ACTION 
 || '  OLD : ' || i.OLD
 || '  NEW : ' || i.NEW);
end loop;
```

end;

Comment: What happens when user issues a `ROLLBACK`? The mail would be sent out anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send mail "after 15 minutes", then don't use a database trigger, they aren't designed to fire with a delay.

Instead, move code you wrote (that sends  into a **stored procedure** and **schedule it** using the `dbms_scheduler` built-in package.

How will you know whether it was 15 minutes after the last DML? You won't, not automatically. Keep logging DMLs into the `EVALUATIONS_LOG`  table and let scheduler run periodically, every 15 minutes. If stored procedure finds something in period `between sysdate and sysdate - interval '15' minute`, send the mail (and mark rows that have been sent so that you wouldn't send them again).

Comment: I took 15 minutes as an example, what i care about is sending dml performed within single email rather than sending multiple ones.

Comment: 15 minutes is irrelevant. Stored procedure + DBMS_SCHEDULER is what matters.

Comment: hi  @littlefoot, i have included the procedure which fetches all the required records, but i want to send the same in mail using a proc  : DLR_SEND_MAIL(mailid,subject,body,from-mail,to_mail)

Comment: Compose the whole e-mail message body in FOR loop (i.e. don't *display* what you found, but store those information into a local variable). Then pass it to DLR_SEND_MAIL procedure which will do its job.

Comment: when i am using variable to store the output and  i am  receiving mail for the only single records, which means the variable is not storing the other values. please suggest something.

Comment: I suggest you debug code you wrote so that it'll return desired result.